# Setting up Linksys wrt54g as seperate lan?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan, wrt54g

I have a question, I don't know if it's in the correct place but sorry if that's the case.
Basically I share the internet connection with my downstairs neighbours (landlords) over wifi, that router is a ZTE H368N.
However I have an old linksys wrt54g lying around here and I would like to use it as my own access point, having it connected to the internet via the H368N router, but separated from their lan and devices, and creating my own "new" lan and broadcast domain.

The problem is they do not want my laying down cables everywhere so I cannot use the ethernet port to connect to it.
Is it possible to do this with this router using wireless?

I've been looking around for tomato and openwrt and such, but most tutorials I found are either talking about a repeater mode where it puts you and all your connected devices on the H368N lan, or it's talking about pulling ethernet cables everywhere, which I am not allowed to do.
Does anybody know if and how this is possible? Or even better maybe know where to find a tutorial?

It currently seems to have ddwrt, and I understand tomato is more noob-proof and openwrt is more difficult to setup?

Comment: Even if possible, keep in mind that this router is a 11g router. It is very slow by today’s standards.

Comment: Yea I figured that, but I guess it's still better than nothing

Comment: If you are using DD-WRT, you can use "Client-Mode" but that will use up the wireless as a "client" to the ZTE. And any internet connectivity you get (in a separate LAN) would be over wired from the Wrt54G to your PC/Laptop. Another option is to simply put the WRT54G next to the ZTE (so a 30cm or less cable from ZTE to the WAN port of the WRT54G sitting next to it) and then you have your own separate LAN over wireless when connecting to the WRT54G. So possible yes - but as @DanielB has mentioned - you may be worse off.

Comment: But then I'd still have to go through the thick concrete floors with my phone, plus they can still mess around with my router if they want to.  Could I use this "Client mode" in combination with for example a raspberry pi and a wifi dongle? Something like that? so one will act as the client to the ZTE, and one will act as the access point for my devices?  Or would that be out of the question?

Comment: OpenWrt has been forked, now it's [LEDE](https://lede-project.org/toh/views/toh_fwdownload), there is already a stable version 17.01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work at first, but I flashed the new ddwrt on it, and setting it up as wireless repeater mode (not bridge) instead of client mode, did exactly what I wanted to.
It is now wirelessly connected to the main router as a client with 192.168.0.7 as ip which is now the wan address, and is rebroadcasting that as a new lan, or actually a vlan I think, as a new seperate wifi connection.
All devices now connected get an ip in subnet 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0, and are completely seperated from the main router as I left all the firewall stuff on.
I can apparantly also use a different dns and ntp server if I want to